# Multiple conditions within an if statement? Methods

Tags: java

If I wanted to check multiple Boolean methods and whether or not they were all true. Would this work assuming all of the methods are booleans and return true/false. Thanks.

```
if (method1() && method2() && method() && method4()) {
  return true
} else {
  return false
}
```

Comment: You can easily try this.

Comment: `return method1() && method2() && method3() && method4();` works fine

Comment: Why don't you just try this and find out? Also, the `if` statement is completely unnecessary in your example in the first place. There's no need to explicitly return `true` and `false` here because you return `true` exactly when `method1() && method2() && method() && method4()` is `true`, and `false` exactly when `method1() && method2() && method() && method4()` is false. You can just return `method1() && method2() && method() && method4()` "directly" without bothering with the `if` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct.

When you join conditions with `&&`, when any condition (starting from the left) will return `false`, conditions that are after him, will not be executed. So:

```
return method1() && method2() && method() && method4();
```

if `method2` will return `false`, `method` and `method4` will not be executed.

*For your information only:*

If you want to call all 4 methods and in the end check if all conditions returned true, then you need to use `&` operator.

```
 return method1() & method2() & method() & method4();
```

Now, even if `method2` returns `false`, `method` and `method4` will be still executed.